# json @consuming only key

Tags: json, rest

when i am getting json in below format

```
{"name":"x","age":23,"language":"java"}
```

i can consume in below way and its working fine.

```
@POST
@Path("/entity")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public SomeSortOfResponse receiveArbitraryJson(Map<String,String> map) {
    // do stuff with map of key-value pairs
}
```

but when i am getting json in below format,

```
{"name","age","id","sex"}
```

how can i consume it in my rest (i tried with list but its giving 400 error).help me in this regard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 400 error is because it cannot parse the json.

```
{"name","age","id","sex"}
```

This is not a valid json object. A json object expects key-value pairs like `"key": "value`. You just have a list of strings. You can pass that in a jsonarray though. Use this:

```
["name","age","id","sex"]
```

Comment: so can i use the same code for consuming                                                           @POST
@Path("/entity")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public SomeSortOfResponse receiveArbitraryJson(Map<String,String> map) {
    // do stuff with map of key-value pairs
}

Comment: or i need to change any thing here?

Comment: @JavaEr Well, json is not always a map of key-value pairs. It can also be an array of values. Sending an array and receiving it as a `Map<String, String>` will not work. But I cannot tell you exactly how to make that work

Comment: @JavaEr you probably want to receive it as a json element and then check if it's an object or an array

Comment: @JavaEr try `List<String> list` instead of the map

Comment: ya its working fine with list now, i made some mistakes in json. thank u so much

Comment: @JavaEr ok you can accept the answer if you like if the problem is solved